# Conversion to PDF

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I want to do a project to convert different file formats to pdf. The file formats are

o Images: .jpg, .tiff, .gif
o Microsoft Word: .doc and .docx
o Microsoft PowerPoint: .ppt and .pptx
o Microsoft Excel: .xls and .xlsx
o Web pages: .htm and .html
o Apple Keynote: .key
o Apple Numbers: .numbers
o Apple Pages: .pages
o Text: .txt

Images and text can be converted to pdf and then stored. But can other file formats be converted. Can any one help with a link or something which promotes this. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you solved the problem??I'm working on converting ppt files to images. Could you give me some advise about that?? Many thanks~

Answer (score 0):

yes, xlsx or pdfx are some kind of xml files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). So you can parse and render the files by your self.

Comment: it's just a few thousand pages of documentation :)

Comment: no i dont think so we need to get the content of the files inorder to convert it to the pdf. But we cannot get the contents of the xls,doc,html,ppt etc